# Show Badge on BottomNavigationView on any activity

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I created an app that has many activities. However, there is one common view in all of them: `BottomNavigationView` at the bottom of the screen.

The xml is as follows:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/btm_nav"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/btm_nav"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_btm_nav" />
```

Now, one of the items in my `BottomNavigationView` is for a chat.

I have a listener in my app that once a new message is recieved, I want it to show a badge on my `BottomNavigationView` by using:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById( R.id.bottom_navigation );
bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge( R.id.chat );
```

How can I add this badge to all of the `BottomNavigationView`'s in my application so that no matter in what activity the user at, it will show the badge?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using fragments?

Comment: No, I dont use it.

Comment: You can use one activity with `BottomNavigationView` and multiple fragments for each item.

Comment: @Armin is right. You can use one Activity with multiple Fragments that way you only have to set BottomNavigationView in the Activity. This is achievable with the help of adapter